# Ahoy Gem Causing No route matches [GET] "/undefined"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ahoy

After installing the Ahoy Gem and adding
`ahoy.trackAll();` to my `application.js`, my application is continually redirected to `/undefined`. I've tried uninstalling and recreating the database, but no luck.

Here's the server log.

```
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `ahoy_events` (`id`, `visit_id`, `name`, `properties`, `time`) VALUES (x'438ffd6f7d4c4291876441fa2b5dcdf0', x'61671132b25b4f169a54ece65dc524b3', '$view', '{\"url\":\"http://localhost:3000/\",\"title\":\"Title\",\"page\":\"/\"}', '2015-08-10 20:12:57')
   (30.7ms)  COMMIT
Completed 200 OK in 161ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 68.8ms)

Started GET "/undefined" for ::1 at 2015-08-10 16:12:59 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/undefined"):
```

Comment: Have you run 
`rails generate ahoy:stores:active_record -d postgresql
rake db:migrate`?
Did you require `//= require ahoy` in `application.js`?

Comment: I ran the mysql equivalent of rails generate. I am requiring ahoy in js and I can access the Javascript methods

Comment: Odd... Have you marked any models `visitable`, and have you tried setting `ahoy.track` in your Ruby instead of your js?

Answer (score 0):

run:

```rb
bundle install
rails generate ahoy:install
rails db:migrate
```

Restart your web server, open a page in your browser, and a visit will be created